# jQuery : How to create a jQuery hover function?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseout

I want to create two functions what fades in and out an element.

This is what I have done so far, but the problem with this is that if you move the mouse while you are in the hovered element it starts vibrating :| How should I make it to not vibrate and work correctly?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function hoverIn(target, speed){
     $(target).fadeIn(speed); 
 }

 function hoverOut(target, speed){
     $(target).fadeOut(speed); 
 }
</script>
```

**[LIVE PREVIEW - check out the problem in live](http://jsbin.com/odama3/2/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this would be using unobtrusive script, the main thing you want is a `.stop()` call to stop the previous animation, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function hoverIn(target, speed){
     $(target).stop(true, true).fadeIn(speed); 
 }

 function hoverOut(target, speed){
     $(target).stop(true, true).fadeOut(speed); 
 }
</script>
```

This is still a problem because [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) fire when entering/leaving a child.  However, [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) uses [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) which don't suffer the same problem, and will eliminate your "vibration" problem.

The unobtrusive version looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul > li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
  }, function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
  });
});​
```

[You can see it here](http://jsbin.com/odama3/5), or the even shorter version:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul > li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 'fast');
  });
});​
```

[You can test that here](http://jsbin.com/odama3/8), note that all of these unobtrusive approaches don't use any inline javascript, and work for multiple child menus.

Comment: Your second example works but its not good for me because I want a function what I can use for any element :)

Comment: @CIRK - It's vibrating because `mouseover` and `mouseout` fire when entering a child...you want `.hover()` here which uses `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` which *don't* fire when entering a child.  You can still attach it to individual elements if you wish.

Comment: Well ok, it works as I wanted it here so thanks very much! :)